# Google Firestore array_contains query doesn't work

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a simple query to find other document that contains some ID. Here is how it looks, and here is what I am trying to get. I don't see a reason for it to work this way. I tried this code for Firestore Functions but it doesn't work.

[image: firestore query]

[image: firestore database]

I tried this code:

```
    exports.updateDietDaysWhenMealChanges = functions.firestore
        .document("Posilek/{posilekId}")
        .onUpdate((change, context) => {
            const posilekId = context.params.posilekId;
            const posilekAfter = change.after.data();

            return db.collection("DietDays")
                .where("Meals", "array-contains", { ID: posilekId })
                .get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.empty) {
                        functions.logger.log("No matching DietDay found");
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return Promise.all(snapshot.docs.map(dietDayDoc => {
                            const dietDayId = dietDayDoc.id;
                            const meals = dietDayDoc.data().Meals;
                            const mealIndex = meals.findIndex(meal => meal.ID === posilekId);
                            meals[mealIndex] = { ID: posilekId, Portions: posilekAfter.Portions };
                            functions.logger.log(`Editing meal in DietDay with ID: ${dietDayId}`);
                            return dietDayDoc.ref.update({ Meals: meals });
                        }));
                    }
                });
        });
```

And I tried manual query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `array-contains` operator can only check for exact matches between items in the array and the value you pass. So in code:

```
.where("Meals", "array-contains", { ID: posilekId, Portions: 12.5 })
```

There is no way to do a partial match.

The common workaround is to add an additional field (e.g. `MealIDs`) that contains just the value you want to filter on:

```
MealIDs: ["ohN....", "..."]
```

With that additional array, you can then filter with:

```
.where("MealIDs", "array-contains", posilekId)
```